# Background Location for react native

Tags: react-native, geolocation, location, react-native-background-fetch

I am creating a react native app for location tracking so I wanted to know how can I work with it.

Requirements:

1. Start tracking location on button click.
2. Fetch both foreground and background location.
3. Fetch location even when the app is killed.
4. Application needs to work with latest Android Version.

Please let me know how can I complete all the above requirements with stable packages.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is to use this library, you have to pay a license tho.

[react-native-background-geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-geolocation)